# Find usages of lombok generated getter/setter in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have a field with lombok annotation (`@Setter`) and I am looking for an easy way to find usages of the auto generated setter.

When I put the cursor on the `@Setter` annotation and run `Find usages` (Alt+F7) I obviously get all the places where `@Setter` annotation is used (the result is all classes which contains lines with `@Setter`)

However I would like to find all places where this concrete setter, for this concrete field  is used (I expect all classes which contains lines with `setSomething(...)` as a result)

I have Annotation Processing enabled (checkbox "Enable annotation processing" in`Settings->Compiler->Annotation Processors` is checked).
I also have Lombok plugin installed and it works fine.

Comment: You should put the cursor on field, not on annotation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should put the cursor on field, not on `@Setter` annotation